# How can I fix having 2 different pytorch versions in different python virtual enviroments running at different speeds on same Ubuntu 20 laptop?

Tags: pytorch

I have gpu rtx 3060-laptop and I have cuda toolkit V11.0.194 and the nvidia driver Version: 520.56.06,CUDA Version: 11.8 and cudnn version 8.7.0.84_cuda11. My laptop is running ubuntu 20.

I created 2 python virtual enviroments using venv for python 3.8. In the first one I installed Pytorch 1.11.0+cu113 and the other I installed Pyotrch Version: 1.7.1+cu110.
I am running the code in here [Autonovel](https://github.com/k-han/AutoNovel) and my main problem is that I run the code in the virtual enviroment containing the newer Pytorch(1.11) and the speed of the code per iteration is 14.5 iteration/s but when I run the same exact code but using virtual enviroment with Pytorch(1.7),the speed of the code is 7 iteration/s. Is that normal? I know the versions of Pytorch I guess should be faster from version to another but double the speed? I feel something wrong. I feel there is something missing in the virtual enviroment containing the old verison of Pytorch 1.7.
Put into consideration that both virtual enviroments donot contain the same exact libraries. The newer virtual enviroment containing the higher versions of pytorch contains many more libraries installed compared to this one but I donot see the affect of this.
Any guesses?

I am really out of ideas in here.

Cheers,
Mostafa Haggag

I tried installing different cudatookit versions, I used to work with 11.6 then I went back to 11.0 but still nothing is fixed. I changed the nvidia driver more than once as I thought it might be the problem but it wasnot.

Comment: The linked repo has several scripts. Please post the exact steps and commands you ran. Please also post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Lastly, you mentioned that double the speed seems wrong; so what do you consider correct (i.e. the desired output) here?

Comment: I do not know what is correct. it's how I can use two different PyTorch versions and they run at different speeds. it seemed to me that there is something wrong. I wanted to ask to understand if someone faced a similar problem with PyTorch 1.7 and we could find slower performance when using an older version in comprised with newer version

Comment: Difference in speed is normal as PyTorch often introduces efficiency improvements with every update (see [their release notes](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/releases)). It’s hard to say more without knowing the exact code that you ran, which is why I asked for an MRE.